# triangle inequality on a given metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, self-learning

$X$ be set consisting of all sequences $(x_1,x_2, \dots)$ s.t $x_i \in \mathbb R$ and $\sum x_i^2$ converges

I need to prove triangle inequality for the metric on $X$ given by,

$d(x,y) = [ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (x_i - y_i)^2]^{\frac12}$

How to go about it? A hint will suffice.

My try after seeing the hint:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2 -2\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i \le | \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2| + | \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2| + 2|\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i|$

Using Cauchy Schwarz:

$| \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2| + | \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2| + 2|\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i| \le | \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2| + | \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2| + 2 (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)^\frac12 (\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)^\frac12 $

So,
$[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2]^\frac12  \le [ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 +  \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2 + 2 (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)^\frac12 (\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)^\frac12]^\frac12 $

How to proceed further.

Comment: is $X$ the set of convergent sequences?

Comment: Yes. $\sum x_i^2$ converges.  I have edited the question

Comment: it suffices to prove that the finite sum $[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2]^{\frac12} \leq [\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i)^2]^{\frac12} + [\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i)^2]^{\frac12}$.  hint: the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is useful.

Comment: For proving the triangle inequality we need to bring in another vector $z \in X$, right?? how come proving only for finite $n$ will do the job?

Comment: the reason for the finite $n$ is this: if you have two  sequences {$a_i$}, {$b_i$} that converge to $a, b$ respectively and $a_i \leq b_i$ for all $i$, then $a \leq b$.  you can prove this for fun.

Comment: yes, you need to bring in another sequence but for this you just use the trick: $x_i - y_i = (x_i - z_i) + (z_i - y_i)$

Comment: I can prove that but how that is relevant in proving the required triangle inequality?

i.e $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$. $\implies [\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(x_i-y_i)^2]^{\frac12} \le [\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(x_i-z_i)^2]^{\frac12} + [\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(z_i-y_i)^2]^{\frac12}$??

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2]^{\frac12} \leq [\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i)^2]^{\frac12} + [\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i)^2]^{\frac12}$ holds for all $x_1, ..., x_n, y_1, ..., y_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and all positive integers $n$, then you can substitute $x_i$ with $x_i - z_i$ and $y_i$ with $y_i - z_i$ because they are real numbers too. Then take the limit as n goes to infinity

Remark:  The partial sums  $\{[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2]^{\frac12}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ can be considered as a sequence and $\{[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i)^2]^{\frac12} + [\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i)^2]^{\frac12}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ can be considered a sequence too.

Comment: I have added my try in my original ques. Could not proceed any further though. Please help!